# What is the most effective strategy to win at this game?

Tags: game-theory

The game is as follows. Alice secretly selects three real numbers $a_{1},a_{2},a_3$ such that $1\geq a_1\geq a_2\geq a_3\geq 0$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3=1$. Bob secretly selects three real numbers $b_{1},b_{2},b_{3}$ such that $1\geq b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq 0$ and $b_1+b_2+b_3=1$ They then compare their numbers. Alice gets one point if $a_i\geq b_i$, and Bob gets one point if $a_i\leq b_i$. The person with the most points wins the game.

For example, If Alice select $\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{8}$ and Bob selects $\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{10}$, then Alice wins because $a_1=\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{3}{5}=b_1$, giving Bob one point, but $a_2=\frac{3}{8}\geq\frac{3}{10}=b_2$ and $a_3=\frac{1}{8}\geq\frac{1}{10}=b_3$, giving Alice two points.

What is the best strategy for this game?

Comment: no strategy wins against all the others, playing random is probably the best. This is similar to rock-paper-scissors

Comment: @Denis: "Random" doesn't mean anything much. You need to specify the distribution you are using.

Comment: @DanielV the numbers have to be ordered, only the first one is correct

Comment: Well...the *worst* strategy for the game seems to be picking $1, 0, 0$...don't know if that helps...

Comment: I'm trying to find a set of moves which on weighted average draw with any other move. Then it would give a (randomized) strategy. We know that there is one such strategy, but I don't even know if it can be finite.

Comment: The problem can be restated as a player choosing $a_3 \in [0~~\frac 13]$ , then $a_2 \in [a_2 ~~ \frac 12 - \frac {a_3}2]$, then $a_1 = 1 - a_2 - a_3$.  To check if a nonrandomized optimum solution exists, check the endpoints: choosing $a_3 = 1/3$ makes $a_2 = 1/3$ and $a_1 = 1/3$, which is beaten by $b_3 = 1/3 + \epsilon$, $b_2 = 1/3 + \epsilon$, $b_1 = 1/3 - 2\epsilon$.  Choosing $a = [1/2, 1/2, 0]$ or $a = [1, 0, 0]$ fails similarly, so the optimal strategy must chose $a_3$ using a distribution.

Comment: By symmetry, if there is an optimal strategy, it's the same for both Alice and Bob, hence the probability of winning is the same $\frac12$. Do you still want an optimal strategy?

Comment: @Macavity: Why not? That is the hard part.

Comment: @DanielV: I am almost sure that the distribution cannot have finite support. I can't even solve the probably easier unordered case.

Comment: Just lazy I guess. I foresee defining a 2D prob distribution on the triangular region bounded by $(0,0), (1,0), (\frac12, \frac12)$ and then optimising it to maximise the integrals... Maybe if I see a shortcut.

Comment: You don't have to consider a triangle, you can do $$\begin{cases} a_3 = \frac 13 x \\ a_2 = \frac 13 x - \frac 12 xy + \frac 12 y \\ a_1 = 1 - \frac 23 x - \frac 12 y + \frac 12 xy \end{cases}$$ and then choose $x$ and $y$ from the square $\{(x,y) ~:~ 0 \le x \le 1 \text{ and } 0 \le y \le 1\}$ and you'll get $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 1$ and $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge 0$ , so it's just converting the problem to one with 2 independent liberties.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy is to choose $a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{1}{3}$, and the probability to win is of $\frac{2}{3}$.

The first thing I did was a program that calculated the probabilities of a given set $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ to win a random $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$. In order to do this, I generated 10000 random sets for Bob using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003967/generate-3-random-number-that-sum-to-1-in-r) and checked how many of them won Alice's given set.

I checked the probabilities for the 210 sets $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ of the form $a_i = 0.05·n, \space\space n\in \mathbb{N}$ and found that the highest ones were close to the combination $a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{1}{3}$. You can check the full table of probabilities I got [here](http://gonthalo.github.io/Probability-Problem/).

In order to find out why this is the optimal distribution, I came up with the following:

All the possible terns $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ that satisfy $1≥a_1≥a_2≥a_3≥0$ can be represented as a triangle in the plane (as pointed out in the comments, we have only two independent parameters):
[image: pic1]

If we now apply the restrictions $a_2\geq a_3$ and $a_2\leq a_1=1-a_2-a_3$ we obtain:
[image]
Let's see in which cases Bob will win if he plays some $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$. In order to win, he must make two of the following inequalities true:
$$
1)\space\space b_2>a_2\\
2)\space\space b_3>a_3\\
3)\space\space b_1>a_1\Leftrightarrow b_2 + b_3 < a_2 + a_3
$$
Let's see when this conditions are fullfilled:
[image: pic3]

If you try to maximize the sum of these three areas, you find that the maximum sum is for $b_2=b_3=\frac{1}{3}$.

This is not exactly right, since not all the points in the triangle have the same probability, but it sort of points out to the right answer.